# What was in the package Nicholson gives to Damon?

Tags: the-departed

After Matt Damon's character in [*The Departed*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0407887/) graduates the state police academy, he is picked up by Costello ("no more pencils, no more books"), and given a box as a graduation present. Though what is contained in the box is never identified, what are some probable theories as to the box's contents?

Comment: It is nothing specific, you decide what is in the box. Sometimes a director doesn't spoon feed every detail. I like the badge answer, it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: I think a watch for some reason too (cliche i guess) after a few viewings i kinda thought it was the knife, only thing is its not that amazing a knife and doesn't seem like a gift so much as something he bought himself. idk i guess its just up to the viewer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The box is a pure [Macguffin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacGuffin).

I've heard some theorize it contained the mobile phone he would go on to use, but I doubt this.

Another theory is that it contains money, or at least something valuable to help him get started up - hence why Costello tells him he's earned it.

Having said that, my own theory is that it is just something personal to Sullivan. It doesn't really matter *what* it is, just that it is something personal which evokes emotion from Sullivan and effectively further establishes the father-son dynamic between Sullivan and Costello for the viewer.

You might be interested to read the [script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Departed,-The.html) for more information. It goes out of its way to point out that the box could contain *anything*:

> **COLIN** walks over to the car. **COSTELLO** gives **COLIN** a **BOX**.
>             **COLIN** flips open the top and then quickly closes it. **NOTE**:
>             The box could contain an eyeball, money, drugs, a picture of
>             Colin fucking his school teacher...we will never know.
>
> **COSTELLO**
>   School's out. You earned it. Yeah, no more teachers, no more books.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter what was in the box. What matters is that Sullivan became a cop moments earlier, and is already accepting gifts from a known criminal. He's fresh out of the academy and has already sold his soul to the devil.

Comment: He "sold his soul to the devil" long before he became a statie. Costello had been mentoring Colin to advance his ventures since Colin was a kid, as shown in the movie's intro. Costello wanted Colin to join the State Police so he'd have a man on the inside, as evidenced by Colin being in a position to warn him that phones were being used to track those involved in a suspected deal to sell computer chips to the Chinese. "School's out," because Colin made it into the department like Costello wanted, and his real work was just beginning.

Answer (score -3):

whats in the box is the knife, same knife that he kills the asian in the back street with

Comment: Welcome to [Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com/tour). Can you provide any sources or proofs to back this claim?

Answer (score -3):

I think it's his detective badge because next scene is him walking to the police plaza as a detective.

Comment: How would Costello, a gangster, have gotten ahold of the badge?

Comment: @JohnnyBones magic!